# Php enlace que tiene una variable

Tags: php, url

tengo un conjunto de resultados que pongo con echo y quiero poner al final un enlace que lleve el id del registro, ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

```
while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC))  
        {               
            echo "<tr align='center'>";
            echo "<td>". $fila['identificacion'] . "</td>";

            echo "<td>". $fila['nombre'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $fila['direccion'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $fila['telefono'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $fila['correo'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $fila['sexo'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $fila['estado_civil'] . "</td>";   
            echo "<td><a href='cliente_editar.php?identiticacion=<?php echo $fila['identificacion']?>'>Editar</a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='cliente_borrar.php'>Borrar</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";           

        }
```

Comment: ¿Dentro del último TD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solo tienes que seguir concatenando como los demás datos... algo así seria...

```
while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC))  
        {               
            echo '<tr align="center">';
            echo '<td>'. $fila['identificacion'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $fila['nombre'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $fila['direccion'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $fila['telefono'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $fila['correo'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $fila['sexo'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $fila['estado_civil'] . '</td>';   
            echo '<td><a href="cliente_editar.php?identiticacion='.$fila['identificacion'].'">Editar</a></td>';
            echo '<td><a href="cliente_borrar.php?identificacion='.$fila['identificacion'].'">Borrar</a></td>';
            echo '</tr>';           

        }
```

pienso que se hace mas fácil trabajar los echo con comillas simple '' y lo de adentro con comillas normales ""...

Comment: Funciona, era eso... gracias Alf